# List de tipo struct, modificar un campo de un struct de una celda del list dejando el resto igual

Tags: c#, lista, struct

Después de buscar varios días por la red no lo he logrado resolver:

```
struct TART
{
    public DateTime time;
    public int color;
    public double altura;
    public string probado;
}

List<TART> LART = new List<TART>();
```

En la `List<TART>` ya hay introducidos varios elementos de tipo `LART`, pero en un momento dado necesito modificar uno de los campos de `LART` de una celda de List, el color por ejemplo, sólo ese campo y el resto (`time`, `altura` y `probado`) dejarlos igual que estaban,  ¿Cómo lo haría?

Yo lo que quiero es tener un array de tupla, es decir, algo que pueda recorrer y que dentro tenga varias variables agrupadas, y que pueda borrar, modificar, añadir cualquier campo. O si hay una forma alternativa más práctica acepto la recomendación.

Comment: De que manera necesitas modificarlo?

Comment: Saludos Miguel, bienvenido a SOes, te invito a dar click: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour -> revisa primero para que veas cómo funciona adecuadamente el sitio. Por otro lado, ¿Por qué estás usando un tipo Struct ?

Comment: yo lo que quiero es tener un array de tupla, es decir, algo que pueda recorrer y que dentro tenga varias variables agrupadas, y que pueda borrar, modificar, añadir cualquier campo, que mejor forma habría?

Comment: @MiguelRs clases es mucho mejor que esto... ve la respuesta...

Comment: OJO, aclaro, clases por lo que estas queriendo hacer.. si casi no cambiaran estaria bien esto...

Answer (score 2):

Cuidado con el uso de los `struct`s. Favorece el uso de `class` a menos que tengas una excelente razón para usar `struct`.

A menos que tus datos no cambien, usar un `struct` para guardar datos que pueden cambiar es casi siempre un error de diseño y van a resultar en comportamiento sorprendente.

Por ejemplo, pongamos que tienes la lista siguiente:

```
List<TART> LART = new List<TART>();
LART.Add(new TART
{
    time = DateTime.Now,
    color = 10,
    altura = 20.5,
    probado = "abc"
});

LART.Add(new TART
{
    time = DateTime.Now,
    color = 5,
    altura = 40.5,
    probado = "zzz"
});
```

Ahora, digamos que deseas cambiar el valor de `color` a `100` para el segundo elemento. Tal vez se te ocurra probar algo así:

```
LART[1].color = 100;
```

... pero esto resulta en el error siguiente:

> Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Collections.Generic.List.this[int]' because it is not a variable

Entonces, tal vez intentes lo siguiente:

```
TART t = LART[1];
t.color = 100;
```

.. que no resulta en un error, pero tampoco funciona correctamente, porque al hacer `TART t = LART[1];`, `t` es ahora tan solo una copia del struct que está en la lista, de modo que solo estarías modificando la copia, y no el elemento que está en la lista.

Para que funcione, estarías obligado a asignar la copia de vuelta a la lista de esta manera:

```
TART t = LART[1]; // obtener copia
t.color = 100; // modificar copia
LART[1] = t; // asignar de vuelta a la lista
```

Nuevamente, mejor define `TART` como una clase en vez de un `struct` para evitar este problema y muchos más. Al definirlo como un `class`, todas las opciones mencionadas arriba funcionarán correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Una estructura es un tipo "casi inmutable". Eso quiere decir que una vez que llenes sus datos, para tocarlos vas a tener que construir algo como una interfaz para poder acceder a modificar los mismos.

Cada vez que hagas una copia de esa estructura, no se va a copiar un puntero a la misma, si no que se va a crear una copia nueva.

Entonces tu soluciones posibles son reemplazar el item en la lista con un item nuevo.

o crear una interfaz para tu estructura que tenga un metodo set para los campos que quieras modificar, y usar ese campo para cambiar los valores.

```
public interface IModificarEstructura
{      String SetColor...       }
public struct TART: IModificarEstructura...

List<TART> LART = new List<TART>();
...
LART [1].SetColor("blanco");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ojo que en c# los struct deben ser diseñados para ser inmutables. te recomiendo esta lectura de por que estos structs son "evils" [Why are mutable structs “evil”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil)

entonces, lo que veo en tu codigo es que tienes un struct inmutable... entonces para hacer lo que quieres debes cambiar tu struct a una clase y todo andaría bien... o hacer tu struct mutable:

```
 struct TART
 {
    public DateTime time;
    public int color;
    public double altura;
    public string probado;

    public TART(Datetime time, int color, double altura, string probado): this()
    {
      this.time = time;
      this.color = color;
      this.altura = altura;
      this.probado = probado;
    }
}

List<TART> LART = new List<TART>();      
//instancias un nuevo lart y agregas un nuevo elemento
LART.Add(new LART( tuTiempo, tuColor, tuAltura , probado));
//tomas una copia del primer elemento y cambias el color
LART[0].Color = 11;
```

Algo así más o menos.

Answer (score 0):

O lo mas sencillo:

```
List<TART> LART = new List<TART>();
LART.Add(new TART { time = DateTime.Now, color = 1, altura = 4, probado = "1" });
LART.Add(new TART { time = DateTime.Now, color = 2, altura = 23, probado = "0" });
LART.Add(new TART { time = DateTime.Now, color = 6, altura = 12, probado = "1" });
LART.Add(new TART { time = DateTime.Now, color = 8, altura = 15, probado = "0" });

TART _tart = LART[3];
_tart.color = 333;
LART[3] = _tart;
```